# Apps and Projects in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am following The Django Book 2.0 for learning Django, and in there, we created a static website called `mysite`. After that, we created an app called `books` with a database. I understand we can create multiple apps under the same project.

However, we can only specify one database in `mysite/settings.py`, which I believe will be used by all apps under the project since it is not specified in `books/`.

How can one create multiple apps that use different databases?

Lastly, what are some use cases of using multiple apps under the same project, while using a static page that's not on an app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) on multiple databases. You can actually list as many databases as you'd like in the DATABASES setting with different names.

Specifically check out the [Routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) section. You can set up routers in each app that will direct your models to use a certain database.

As far as use cases for multiple apps while using a static page that's not on an app, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you're talking about static webpages you can use [flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/). It is an optional django application that allows you to store HTML in a database to be edited from the admin.

Comment: +1 for answering both parts of his question. There is also the [`direct_to_template`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template) generic view that is more basic, and unlike flatpages, it will go through any view middleware.

Answer (score 3):

In Django you define multiple databases like so:

In your settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```

here I have defined 2 databases a default and user, to know more about how to sync or use these database [follow this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)